# How to extract each character in a textarea using Javascript (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a straight forward classic ASP page that uses a  where the user can enter any standard keyboard key plus the Enter key (and even special ALT nnn values if they so desire)

The current HTML code is as follows:

```
Enter your message - Characters left &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="chl" value="<%=Cclen%>" size=3 diabled readonly>
<br />
<textarea id="SMSmsg" name="SMSmessage" MAXLENGTH="600" rows=5 cols=35 onKeyUp="textCounter(this)"></textarea>
```

The JavaScript function **testcounter** currently uses **indexOf("\n")** which goes through the entire **textarea** every time a key is released.  I also need to determine if other special chars have been entered as they coult for 2 chars when sending an SMS

In summary, can anybody suggest some JS code that will let me determine each char that the user has entered (preferably turn it into it's ascii value) so I can then accurately work out the char count and display it to the user if it exceeds the **160 limit** but I can also handle 306 chars and up to 457 chars when sending SMS texts

Perhaps the **MATCH** function could be the go as it would only have to check the entire string once but any other **suggestions** much appreciated

Thanks in advance and apologies if anybody needs the JS code

Comment: *"...apologies if anybody needs the JS code"* Yes, posting the code is a requirement.

Comment: Use `split('')` to get the individual characters entrered, then `charCodeAt()` for each character to get its ASCII value

Comment: @tewathia [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) does not return _ASCII_ values but _Unicode_ ones (up to `65536` before going into surrogates)

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, but isn't the Unicode value of every character that has an ASCII value same as its ASCII?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to listen for the *keypress* event, however, then what happens when you get a user pasting into the `<textarea>`? Further, *JavaScript* doesn't let you choose character encodings and does everything in *UTF-16*, not *ASCII*.

As you want to count the bytes, the best solution for you may actually be to convert to *Blob* and take the *size*

```
function getByteLength(str_data) {
    var b = new Blob([str_data]);
    return b.size;
}

getByteLength('a\u2020b'); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfCharacters = document.getElementById('SMSmsg').value.split('');
var numberOfCharacters = arrayOfCharacters.length;
```

Comment: This won't help with finding byte length